# Tales of Graces: Does a chest have to be empty to count as "opened"?

Tags: tales-of-graces-f

There is at least one title in the game for opening as many trasure chests as you can.  Sometimes when you open a chest, your inventory is already full of that item, and it gives you the option to discard or put it back.

In this case of surplus items, does the chest have to be empty to count as "opened"? Or will the game still recognize it if you put the item back?